# Getting unique iOS device information using React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native for iOS development and having issues with getting unique device information. Getting the Mac address, a UUID or device name would be fine. Does Apple not allow you to gather this data?

Comment: https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info

Comment: @Shawn J Williams Device info is definitely really good :)

Comment: @parohy  Any working examples of this library. I've worked with it today and previously and could not get it to run properly. My build would fail due to the tv.os targets or my function would return undefined.

Comment: @ShawnJWilliam Do you need to have tvOS schema? Just remove it from the project

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any built in API in react-native to gather this information (someone correct me if I am wrong). However, you can try out one of a few libraries

Ios specific - generates a UUID once every time the app is installed

https://github.com/lazywei/react-native-device-uuid

Gathers more information than the previous such as device model, manufacturer, etc. Also gets a unique device ID

https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info

Comment: I've been working with  the library https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info for most of the day to get device info. The tv.os target is causing some issue but I think there is a work around

Comment: I've had some issues with it also but needed it for a unique device id as well. I ended up forking the repo and fixing it to suit my needs. Let me know if you run into any other issues, maybe its something I've experienced also and can help